# Adding new analysis scheme in CloudSearch still doesn't return results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to add some synonyms and aliases for text searches via the AWS CloudSearch console. I followed the instructions in [Configuring Text Analysis Schemes for Amazon CloudSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html), but a test search still doesn't match on my alias.

I configured a scheme called `default` along with the following synonym JSON:

```
{
  "auto-tune": [
    "autotune"
  ]
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed an important note in the documentation:

> To use an analysis scheme, you must apply it to one or more text or text-array fields and rebuild the index. You can configure a field's analysis scheme from the Indexing Options page. To rebuild your index, click the Run Indexing button.